# PHP: Setting variable for parent class

Tags: php, class, variables, inheritance

I have

```
class Meat extends Food {
$var = Food::foodFunction…
}
```

I need to set $var for the Food class, how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Class `Food` is undefined in your example. Normally by how extending works, there actually is no class `Food`, there is only `Meat` in `$this` - but that should be no problem because `Meat` has everything `Food` has.

Comment: You need to set `Food::$var` and  it is static? If so `parent::$var = 'value'` otherwise, you cannot set an instance variable for a parent. It merely exists in the child via `$this->var`

Comment: Code-Example: http://codepad.org/bqhtaVoJ , you are probably looking for the `parent` keyword.

Comment: Extremely unclear and doesn't answer to clarifications requested in the comments. I know it's an old question but -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the constructor or some other member function by using `$this`:

```
function __construct() {
    $this->var = Food::foodFunction();
}
```

Otherwise, you cannot initialize `$var` to anything that is not static.

Answer (score 5):

If `$var` in the food class is a `protected` / `public` variable you just do with `$this->var`, if it's `private` you can't set it

Comment: Beware that if you edit a parent variable, those edits are visible only inside the inherited class. It doesn't make lot of sense.